# Selecting valid entry and exit records

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

The following is a sample from the table I have

```
F_ID     R_ID       DATE    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C  Day_Rec  Update_No
 12      158      20161008    01      99     99     1        -
 12      158      20161012    01      01     99     1        -
 12      158      20161019    01      02     10     1        -
 12      158      20161019    99      01     10     2        1
 12      158      20161019    99      02     10     2        2
 12      160      20161006    01      99     01     1        -
 12      160      20161006    01      99     02     2        1
 12      160      20161011    99      01     99     1        -
 17      167      20161013    99      01     01     1        - 
 17      167      20161016    99      02     99     1        -
 17      167      20161020    02      01     10     1        -
 17      174      20161010    99      01     01     1        -
 17      174      20161012    01      02     11     1        -
 17      174      20161017    99      02     10     1        -
 17      174      20161017    99      96     10     2        1
 17      174      20161017    99      07     10     2        2
 17      174      20161017    99      99     10     2        3
```

For each  F_ID, R_ID:

```
When Col_A or Col_B = '01' and Col_C <>'10' - **It is an entry record**
When Col_C = '10' - **It is an exit record**

Day_Rec = 1 means it is the first entry on that date
Day_Rec = 2 means it is the modification on the same date

Update_No - Incremental modification tracker

Update_No is missing when Day_Rec = 1 because its not a modification 
Update_No = 1 or 2 or 3..... when Day_Rec = 2 modified multiple times on same date
```

There can be multiple modifications on the same date but still Day_Rec would be 2 only. The multiple updates are tracked by Update_No

Logic here is

```
1. Select the earliest valid entry record. 
   If there is a modification on that earliest date select the entry record with Day_Rec = 2 and highest Update_No 
   **and** 
2. Select the latest exit record.
   If there is a modification on that latest date select the exit record with Day_Rec = 2 and highest Update_No  for each F_ID, R_ID
```

I want to select such that I get one valid entry record and one valid exit record for each F_ID and R_ID. Only if each F_ID and R_ID both have valid entry and exit records

```
F_ID   R_ID    DATE     Col_A   Col_B   Col_C  Day_Rec Update_No
12     158    20161008    01      99     99      1       -      ->  Entry record
12     158    20161019    99      02     10      2       2      ->  Exit Record
17     167    20161013    99      01     01      1       -      ->  Entry record
17     167    20161020    02      01     10      1       -      ->  Exit Record
17     174    20161010    99      01     01      1       -      ->  Entry record
17     174    20161017    99      99     10      2       3      ->  Exit Record
```

I have the following query to get sort entry and exit records by date

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT your_table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F_ID, R_ID order by DATE) as rn, 'Entry record' as rec FROM your_table WHERE (Col_A = '01' or Col_B = '01') and Col_C <> '10'
    union all
SELECT your_table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F_ID, R_ID order by DATE DESC) as rn, 'Exit record' as rec FROM your_table WHERE Col_C = '10'
) t3
where rn = 1
ORDER BY F_ID, R_ID, DATE
```

But how do I take into account 'Day_Rec' or 'Update_No' fields. Also it doesnt get me the "only if both entry and exit records exists for each F_ID and R_ID" condition

**Update:**

I have tried the 'Case when' at the beginning of the select queries without luck. I cant seem to get how to select max(Update_No) if Day_Rec = 2 within the where condition for entry and exit records

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the first entries per `f_id` and `r_id`. Then outer join the latest modification on those `f_id`, `r_id` and date. (As of 12c you can use `OUTER APPLY` for this.)
2. Do the same for exits.
3. `UNION ALL` the two queries.
4. Take the result and only stay with those `f_id` and `r_id` where there are two rows in the result set.

The query:

```
select f_id, r_id, dte, col_a, col_b, col_c, day_rec, update_no 
from
(
  select 
    both.*,
    count(*) over (partition by f_id, r_id) as cnt
  from
  (
    select 
      e.f_id, 
      e.r_id, 
      e.dte, 
      coalesce(m.col_a, e.col_a) as col_a,
      coalesce(m.col_a, e.col_a) as col_b,
      coalesce(m.col_a, e.col_a) as col_c,
      coalesce(m.day_rec, e.day_rec) as day_rec,
      m.update_no
    from
    (
      select
        your_table.*,
        row_number() over(partition by f_id, r_id order by dte) as rn
      from your_table 
      where (col_a = '01' or col_b = '01') and col_c <> '10' and day_rec = 1
    ) e
    left join
    (
      select
        your_table.*,
        row_number() over(partition by f_id, r_id, dte order by update_no desc) as rn
      from your_table 
      where (col_a = '01' or col_b = '01') and col_c <> '10' and day_rec > 1
    ) m on m.f_id = e.f_id and m.r_id = e.r_id and m.dte = e.dte and m.rn = 1
    where e.rn = 1
    union all
    select 
      e.f_id, 
      e.r_id, 
      e.dte, 
      coalesce(m.col_a, e.col_a) as col_a,
      coalesce(m.col_a, e.col_a) as col_b,
      coalesce(m.col_a, e.col_a) as col_c,
      coalesce(m.day_rec, e.day_rec) as day_rec,
      m.update_no
    from
    (
      select
        your_table.*,
        row_number() over(partition by f_id, r_id order by dte) as rn
      from your_table 
      where col_c = '10' and day_rec = 1
    ) e
    left join
    (
      select
        your_table.*,
        row_number() over(partition by f_id, r_id, dte order by update_no desc) as rn
      from your_table 
      where col_c = '10' and day_rec > 1
    ) m on m.f_id = e.f_id and m.r_id = e.r_id and m.dte = e.dte and m.rn = 1
    where e.rn = 1
  ) both
)
where cnt = 2;
```